# Why do I suddenly have to fully refresh (CTRL + R) each page I visit in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

First of, some revelant tidbits about my browsing-related settings:

- Xubuntu 13.10
- Firefox 27.0.1, to which I updated this morning I believe.
- I did not change any proxy settings in Firefox.
- The problem does not occur in Chromium.

Active add-ons are:

- Noscript 2.6.8.14
- Reddit Enhancement Suite 4.3.1.2
- Ubuntu Firefox Modifications 2.8

Since my latest boot, which was circa 2 hours ago, I have to "full refresh" every single page I visit. It says "Page not found" on each first visit, whether it is askubuntu.com, reddit.com, twitter.com and so forth. Sometimes I even have to hit `Ctrl + R` twice or thrice. Before this, I think in the last 24 hours, I sometimes (although in a very rare fashion) experienced some pages not loading fully.

What is causing this? How can I solve this issue?

### Additional info after DK Bose's posts

With all extensions disabled it worked sporadically better I'd, but sometimes just as buggy, for example with [ubuntu-manual.org](https://imgur.com/rAYDOBd).

Starting Firefox [with a new profile (via `firefox -ProfileManager`)](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles) also didn't change things:

- reddit.com wasn't found: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADYTu.jpg
- ubuntuusers.de was loaded only partially: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0zFj.jpg

I'd say it was equally bad. As reddit.com and ubuntuusers.de were loaded just normally in Chromium, it seems to be connected to Firefox on Ubuntu. Hm... really do not have a clue what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

There are some things to do which help diagnose and hopefully solve your problem.

- Use the *Restart with Addons Disabled* option under `Help`. This is also called [Safe mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode) and the link explains its use.
- Use the *Reset Firefox* option available under `Help`, `Troubleshooting Information`. That is explained in [Reset Firefox – easily fix most problems](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems).
- Of course, you can also do somethings yourself:

  - empty your cache by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Delete</kbd> and choosing appropriate options.
  - create a new profile by starting Firefox from a terminal using `firefox -P`. This will invoke a window which allows you to create a new profile. If you don't have the problem with the new profile, you could migrate several useful things like bookmarks and passwords over to the new profile. This maybe necessary if something in your olde profile corrupted and is difficult to trace.

I also use Firefox and have not had problems but one of the methods listed above should help you!

---

I realize I have not said what could cause the problem because I have not met it myself and not seen discussion of it elsewhere!

Comment: Yup, the question isn't answered but the problem was solved. I deleted *everything* via `CTRL + SHIFT + DEL` and now I can browse normally again.

Comment: Actually, it wasn't. My flatmate reported the same problem on his Windows machine. He then reconfigured the DNS something something in the router to another server of our internet provider and now says the problem is solved. So far I can say the same but I'm staying cautious. Never experienced that DNS servers show that kind of faulty performance, it's a bit odd.